# Limes superior and inferior inequalities with functions and its derivatives

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives, limsup-and-liminf

*Lemma 2.* from N.H. Duu, *On The Existence of Bounded Solutions for Lotka- Volterra Equations*, Acta Mathematica Vietnamica 25(2) (2000), 145-159.

> Let $G(t)$ and $F(t)$ be two diferentiable functions defined on
>   $(0,\infty)$ such that $\lim_{t\to\infty} G(t) = \lim_{t\to\infty}F(t)
>  = +\infty$ then $$\limsup_{t\to\infty}\frac{G(t)}{F(t)}\leq \limsup_{t\to\infty}\frac{G'(t)}{F'(t)};
>  \quad\liminf_{t\to\infty}\frac{G(t)}{F(t)}\geq
>  \liminf_{t\to\infty}\frac{G'(t)}{F'(t)}.$$
>
> Proof. By the Cauchy theorem for diferential functions, for any
>   $t_{1}, t_{2} > 0$ there is an $\theta \in (t_{1}, t_{2})$ such that
>   $$\frac{G'(\theta)}{F'(\theta)}=\frac{G(t_{1})-G(t_{2})}{F(t_{1})-F(t_{2})}=\dfrac{G(t_{2})}{F(t_{2})}\times\dfrac{1-\dfrac{G(t_{1})}{G(t_{2})}}{1-\dfrac{F(t_{1})}{F(t_{2})}}.$$
>   Letting $t_{1}$ and $t_{2} \to \infty$ such that $\lim\dfrac{G(t_{1})}{G(t_{2})}
>  = lim \dfrac{F(t_{1})}{F(t_{2})}= 0$ we get the result.

Can anybody help me understand the last part of this proof? Exactly, how this transformation $$\frac{G'(\theta)}{F'(\theta)}=\frac{G(t_{1})-G(t_{2})}{F(t_{1})-F(t_{2})}=\dfrac{G(t_{2})}{F(t_{2})}\times\dfrac{1-\dfrac{G(t_{1})}{G(t_{2})}}{1-\dfrac{F(t_{1})}{F(t_{2})}} \text{where} \lim_{t_1,t_2\to\infty}\dfrac{G(t_{1})}{G(t_{2})}
 = \lim_{t_1,t_2\to\infty} \dfrac{F(t_{1})}{F(t_{2})}= 0$$ leads to inequalities from lemma?

Comment: Is there something missing? For $G(t) = t$, for instance, $t_1/t_2$ does not converge. Let alone to $0$.

Comment: No, this is full lemma and its proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cited proof lacks many details. So I expand the limit superior version. The inferior version is analogous.

1. Since $F(t) \to \infty$ for $t\to\infty$ we may assume that $F > 0$ without lost of generality.
2. Fix some $t_1\in (0,\infty)$. We may assume that for every $t > t_1$ it follows $F(t) > F(t_1)$.
3. By Cauchy mean value theorem, for each $t_2 > t_1$ there exists some $\theta \in (t_1, t_2)$ with
   $$ 
   \frac{G(t_2) - G(t_1)}{F(t_2)} 
   \le \frac{G(t_2) - G(t_1)}{F(t_2) - F(t_1)} 
   = \frac{G'(\theta)}{F'(\theta)}
   \le \sup_{t > t_1} \frac{G'(t)}{F'(t)}
   =: M(t_1).
   $$
4. In particular for $t_2 > t_1$, we have
   $$ 
   \frac{G(t_2)}{F(t_2)}
   = \frac{G(t_2) - G(t_1)}{F(t_2)} + \frac{G(t_1)}{F(t_2)}
   \le M(t_1) + \frac{G(t_1)}{F(t_2)}.
   $$
5. Compute the limit superior with respect to $t _2 $:
   $$
   \limsup_{t_2\to\infty} \frac{G(t _2)}{F(t _2)} \le M(t_1) + 0.
   $$
   Notice that the left-hand-side becomes independent of $t_1$.
6. Now apply the limit with respect to $t_1$:
   $$
   \limsup_{t _2\to\infty} \frac{G(t _2)}{F(t _2)} \le \lim_{t_1\to \infty} M(t_1) 
   = \limsup_{t\to\infty} \frac{G'(t)}{F'(t)}.
   $$
   And we are done.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!